# Pandas groupby nunique output to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have as input a dataset like the following:

```
labels = ['chrom', 'start', 'end', 'read']
my_data = [['chr1', 784344, 800125, 'read1'],
           ['chr1', 784344, 800124, 'read2'],
           ['chr1', 784344, 800124, 'read3']]
```

Which I convert to a pandas dataframe using:

```
my_data_pd = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_data, columns=labels)
```

and that looks like this:

```
  chrom   start     end   read
0  chr1  784344  800125  read1
1  chr1  784344  800124  read2
2  chr1  784344  800124  read3
```

What I want to do is the following: I wan't merge the rows that have indentical chrom,start,end values, and count the number of disntinct occurences of the values in the **'read'** column for those rows that were merged. Finally, I want to convert convert that output to a list/tuple, as in this example (note that the last column has the count information):

```
[('chr1', 784344, 800125,1), ('chr1', 784344, 800124,2)]
```

What I have  been able to do:

Unsing **Pandas Groupby** and the **nunique()** with the command:

```
my_data_pd.groupby(['chrom','start','end'],sort=False).read.nunique()
```

I arrive to a Pandas.Series object that looks to what I want:

```
chrom  start   end   
chr1   784344  800125    1
               800124    2
Name: read, dtype: int64
```

However, when I convert it to a list/tuple using:

```
 sortedd.index.tolist()
```

the last column gets excluded, leading to the resulting output:

```
[('chr1', 784344, 800125), ('chr1', 784344, 800124)]
```

Any idea about how can I get around trough this problem?

For all those that might come up with a solution, I am doing this inside a big program thousands of times, so speed is a big issue. Thats the reason I am avoiding other tools like **BedTools** and **pybedtools**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then in `list comprehension` convert to `tuples`:

```
L = [tuple(x) for x in sortedd.reset_index().values.tolist()]
print (L)
[('chr1', 784344, 800125, 1), ('chr1', 784344, 800124, 2)]
```

Comment: This was simple :)

Comment: I was thinking using this way ..nice for tuple (PS: I forget how to get the tuple ..)

Comment: @Dark - and dont forget also upvote question, I think it is nice ;)

Comment: @Wen- and dont forget also upvote question, I think it is nice ;)

Comment: This one seems to be the fastest :) many thanks to all for your fast answers!

Answer (score 3):

You can `set_index`

```
sortedd.to_frame('val').set_index('val',append=True).index.tolist()
Out[277]: [('chr1', 784344, 800125, 1), ('chr1', 784344, 800124, 2)]
```

Comment: I was wondering the presence of append. Seeing it today after all these days

Answer (score 3):

You can use multi index i.e

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(sortedd.reset_index().values.T)

idx.tolist()
[('chr1', 784344, 800125, 1), ('chr1', 784344, 800124, 2)]
```